# Can't add component 'Animation' totestObj because such a component is already added to the game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to AddoCompornent "Animation" in the Update() function of the script to testObj.

I wrote and executed the following code, but I get an error.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class unityRecieve : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called 
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("testObj");
        obj.AddComponent<Animation>();
    }
}
```

The error details are as follows.

```
Can't add component 'Animation' totestObj because such a component is already added to the game object!
```

How can I skip the processing if the Animation Compornent has already been added to the Gameobject?

I need to rename "testObj" dynamically, so I want to handle it in the Update () function instead of in the Startup () function.

I want to AddComponent after checking if Animation component is already added to testObj using if statement as follows. However, an error occurs if the following method is used. I don't know the correct way.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class unityRecieve : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animation animation;

    // Start is called 
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("testObj");
        animation = GetComponent<Animation>(obj);
        if(animation == null)
        {
            obj.AddComponent<Animation>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you not understand about the message? And why are you trying to do it **every frame**? Move your code to the `Start` method... Or if you need `Update` use a `bool` for doing it only once ... `Find` is extremely slow and shouldn't be used too much **at all* and even less in `Update`, you could check if the component already was added using `GetComponent` but again .. it is very slow and should never be used in `Update` ... What's your exact usecase here?

Comment: I want to create an Animation for an object entered in an external application using UDP communication. Flag will be used to check if this is the first loop, and "Find" will be executed only once in the Update () function. If the object name is changed in the external application, run "Find" again.

Comment: But after renaming is it a new object or do you just rename it? I mean why should the reference change of the object only gets a new name? And why do you have to add the component again? And actually why don't you just create the object / a prefab which already has the `Animator` right from the beginning?

Comment: If I use this by myself, I can change the script myself. But I want to distribute this code to many people who can't read the code. When that happens, I expect the object name to change depending on the person using it. I want to add a component only once.

Comment: Sorry buddy it's probably me but I still don't understand what is the whole purpose of it? Can't you just reference the according object e.g. in a field right from the beginning? Or alternatively in your code where you rename the object you already seem to have the according reference so add the `Animator` there? Currently I only see you using `Find` with a hardcoded name .. how/when/where will it be changed?

Comment: Not a complicated story, I want to know if AnimationComponet is already attached to an object using an "if statement". I don't know how. Sorry for the poor explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'ld say the exception message is self-explanatory enough.

---

You can ofcourse simply use

```
if(!obj.GetComponent<Animation>())
    obj.AddComponent<Animation>();
```

---

However, as mentioned in the comments both `Find` and `GetComponent` are **very expensive** calls and should **never** be done in `Update`. In general you should avoid them as much as possible.

---

An alternative might be e.g.

void Update()
    {
        if(isInitialized) return;

```
    var obj = GameObject.Find("testObj");
    obj.AddComponent<Animation>();
    isInitialized = true;
}
```

But also this is quite inefficient. You should rather simply do it only **once** and only when the UDP command is received.

---

I still don't see the reason why you can't

- add the `Animation` to the `GameObject` via the Inspector <kbd>Add Component</kbd> by default before even starting the App
- create a Prefab which already has the `Animation` attached (via the Inspector <kbd>Add Component</kbd>)
- use `Find` only **once** in `Start` and store the reference to it in a field
- in general already reference the `obj` in a field via the Inspector

Comment: I'm assuming a code that receives smartphone tilt information as character string data tens of times per second via UDP. It contains the object name. So, when I receive UDP, it can't be just once.I didn't know that there was Prefab. When I played in Unity, Animation was temporarily AddComponent. However, when Unity was stopped, Component disappeared and I was in trouble.