# How can I keep AddComponent after stopping Unity script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried code like below.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class unityRecieve : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called 
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("Cube");
        obj.AddComponent<Animation>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

When I press the Start button in Unity, Animation is AddComponent as shown in the image below.
[image]

However, if I press the Start button again to stop Unity, AddComponent disappears as shown in the following image.
[image]

I want to keep the Animation Component without erasing it even when the script stops playing in Unity. What should I do now?

I want to create animation dynamically in Unity and bake its motion, but when I stop it, AddComponent disappears so I can't bake.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [ExecuteInEditMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html)

Comment: Its disappearing because you are doing it at runtime..

Answer (score 2):

Don't do AddComponent from the script as it will run only in play mode.

You should select the gameobject where you want to add the component and click on 'Add component' in inspector and then search and add the 'Animation' component instead of doing it in the script.

Comment: @taichi that's what I ment btw when I said add the component via the Inspector before even running the App/PlayMode in [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58850549/7111561)

Answer (score 0):

Changes made to any game objects in the scene at run time will not persist after pressing stop. The Play and Stop buttons simulate launching and closing the game in a debug environment. What you are asking about would be similar to booting up a game and having the levels change each time as you play through them when characters or object moves around the scene. Hopefully that makes sense. To make direct changes to the scene you need to make your changes through the inspector which is the window on the right, where you see the components attached to the Game Object that you have selected.